# Avoiding running aux file many times

Tags: bibtex

My main tex has the structure as below;

Main.tex

```
 \input{preamble.tex}

 \begin{document}

 \include{ch1.tex} within ch1.tex => \bibliographystyle{agsm}, \bibliography{ch1.bib}

 \include{ch2.tex} within ch2.tex => \bibliographystyle{agsm}, \bibliography{ch2.bib}

 \include{ch3.tex} within ch3.tex => \bibliographystyle{agsm}, \bibliography{ch3.bib}

\end{document}
```

My compiling order:

xelatex => Main.tex

Bibtex => ch1.aux, Bibtex => ch2.aux, Bibtex => ch3.aux

xelatex  1 or 2 times.

to make bibliography correctly at the end of each chapter.

My question:

1. Is there another way to compile that without running every aux files for each chapter? Using something to detect all aux files automatically and run them all.
2. Alternative ways are welcome.

Comment: if you want to update the bibliography you will have to run that. But normally your editor should take care of it, mine simply calls all needed bibtex run if I start with bibtex main. You can also use arara or latexmk. The alternative is to use biblatex + biber, then you need only one biber run (but this will require changes to your document).

Comment: latex always reads all the aux files your issue seems to be that you are choosing per-chapter bibliographies so you need to run bibtex to generate each bibliography, which seems quite natural. It shouldn't be an issue you only need to run it occasionally, after you have added a \cite,  it is not as if you need to run bibtex multiple times, or even at all, after each edit.